# Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'p-multiSelect'

Tags: angular, datatable, primeng

I am trying to implement [datatable filter of primeng](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/filter).
My code is as below:

```html
<p-column field="time" header="Time" [filter]="true" filterPlaceholder="&#xf0b0;">
  <ng-template pTemplate="filter">
    <p-multiSelect [options]="time"></p-multiSelect>
  </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

But it is showing an error: **Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'p-multiSelect'.**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to import **`import {MultiSelectModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
'`** in your module.ts under imports

```
imports: [
  MultiSelectModule
]
```

Comment: I add this, but still issue is not fixed . Any reason?

Comment: @Gobi , also include BrowserAnimationsModule, FormsModule before this import

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Angular CDK. Use **npm install @angular/cdk --save** command.
Import multi select module in yourModule.module using

```
import {MultiSelectModule} from 'primeng/multiselect';
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I had to install angular cdk using next command:

`npm install @angular/cdk --save`

Then I had to manually write both lines of codes of imports (without auto-completion, for some reason), but after first start everything was successfully compiled and working.

```
import { MultiSelectModule } from 'primeng/multiselect';

(...)

imports:[
   MultiSelectModule
]
```

You can read more about MultiSelect from their official documentation:
https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/multiselect